# How to add header to Users based on the lastname?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have this data of users (already sorted by lastname in backEnd - no need to sort anything) that I need to separate in Sections.

For example for users that their lastname starts with "A" I would like to add a header called **"A"** above all of those users, for users that lastname starts with **"B"** I would like to add a header **"B"**, so on and so forth.

Something like this:

```
A
Albertson, Mike
Aprot, Paul
Art, Boris
Amnb, Luis
Alop, Steven
Arnt, Carl

B
Benet, Marth
Bolt, Luis
Bernt, laura
Burn, Steven
Ball, Carl

C
Cak, Lori
Callart, Ben
Cort, Mary
Curll, Carl

D
Dust, Peter
Dorll, Lonm
Dori, Pern
Dern, Trevor

E
No users available

F
Ford, Doris
Fret, Trevor
Fortran, Mario
...
...
...
```

so far I can render the users but I'm having trouble adding the header to each section. My Goal is to add a header from **"A to Z"**. Now, if one of the sections is empty I still would like to render the header and say: **"No users available"**. In my real app I may have 80 users for each section or even more. What will be the best approach to this?

Here's my code:

```
 ngOnInit() {
   this.myService.getUsers()
     .subscribe(res => this.people = res);
 }
```

[**LIVE DEMO HERE**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-4qdbnq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Please check my angular plugin. it can help. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-group-by-alphabetes.

Comment: `@progx` demo added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider usings lodash's `groupBy` and the `keyvalue`pipe in template.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let group of people | keyvalue">
  <div>{{ group.key }}</div>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let user of group.value">
      {{ user.lastname }},
      {{ user.name }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</ng-container>
```

```
this.myService.getUsers().subscribe(res => this.people = groupBy(res, _ => _.lastname.charAt(0)));
```

See also stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-rpxtf2?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: How would you show a message "No users available" for a section that doesn't have users?. My goal is to render headers from A to Z no matter what. But render that message if there are no users

Comment: You could create an "empty" object and then spread it with the lodash result displayObject = { ...displayObject, ...groupedObject }

Comment: @MoxxiManagranm can you provide an stackblitz?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-bptrg2?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input! Voting it up

Answer (score 1):

You basically 1) `reduce` on a empty map to group the people based on the first letter of their last name 2) use `ngFor` on two layers (1 for each group, 1 for each person in the corresponding group) to display everything

Unfortunately if you want to display all letters, I think you are pretty much stuck with keeping a list of letters. Which isn't too bad but a little bit ugly

```
letters: String[] = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T','U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'] 

ngOnInit(){
  this.myService.getUsers()
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.people = res // You don't actually need this 
        let groupedPeople = this.people.reduce((groups, contact) => {
          var letter = contact.lastname.charAt(0); //get the first letter which will be the key
          groups[letter] = groups[letter] || []; // Either init an array of people for that key or use the existing one
          groups[letter].push(contact); // Add the entry
          return groups;
        }, {});
        this.displayGroups = letters
           .map(key => ({key, contacts: groupedPeople[key]}));
      });
}
```

And in your component

```
<ul>
 <li *ngFor="let group of displayGroups">
    <h3 class="group">{{group.key}}</h3> 
    <ng-container *ngIf="group.contacts">
      <div *ngFor="let contact of group.contacts">
        {{contact.lastname}}
        {{contact.name}}
      </div>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="!group.contacts">
      No users available
    </ng-container>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Note that I handle the empty case when rendering. There isn't a reason to pollute the list with "placeholders"

You will have to clean this up a little bit, there is a few redundant lines you can get rid of

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-uqlwy9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: How would you show a message "No users available" for a section that doesn't have users?. My goal is to render headers from A to Z no matter what. But render that message if there are no users

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Consider implementing it using **RXJS** as demonstrated below:

**1. Interface:**

```js
interface User {
  name: string;
  lastname: string;
}

interface Group {
  header: string;
  users: User[]
}
```

**2. Component:**

```js
this.myService.getUsers().pipe(
  switchMap(users => range(65, 26)
    .pipe(
      map(x => String.fromCharCode(x)),
      map(header => {
        return ({ header, users: users.filter(x => x.lastname.charAt(0) == header) })
      }),
      toArray(),
    )
  )
)
```

**3. Template:**

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let group of groups$ | async">
  <h2>{{group.header}}.</h2>

  <ng-container *ngIf="group.users.length; else elseTemplate">
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let user of group.users">
        {{user.lastname}} {{user.name}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-template #elseTemplate>No users available</ng-template>
</ng-container>
```

[Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-brook-gzxbz?file=/src/app/app.component.ts)

**Optionally** using `groupBy` operator: (for better performance)

```js
this.myService.getUsers()
  .pipe(
    groupBy((user) => user.lastname.charAt(0)),
    mergeMap((group) => zip(of(group.key), group.pipe(toArray()))),
    reduce(
      (acc, [key, users]) => acc.set(key, users),
      new Map<string, User[]>()
    ),
    withLatestFrom(
      range(65, 26).pipe(
        map((x) => String.fromCharCode(x)),
        toArray()
      )
    ),
    map(([map, letters]) =>
      letters.map((header) => ({ header, users: map.get(header) }))
    )
  );
```

[Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-villani-ppfk2?file=/src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score -1):

It would be much simpler to have them grouped in an array with key/values from backend, with the letter as the key, and an array of users which start with this letter as a value.

If you insist on doing it that way this should work

```
 letters = ['A', 'B' , .... , 'Z']; 
 users = [];
 usersByLetters = [];

this.userService.getUsers()
.subscribe(res => this.users = res)

checkForLetter(letter){
   //reset the array
   this.usersByLetter = [];
   this.users.map(user => {
        //compare the letter passed as a parameter to the first letter of 
         // the names, make sure both either uppercase or lowercase
        
           if(letter == user.charAt(0)){
              this.usersByLetter.push(user)
           }
   });
   if the array contains users, return true and display them
   return this.usersByLetter.length > 0;
}
```

Then is your html do the following

```
<div class="letters" *ngFor="let letter of letters">
  <div class="letter-box">
     <p>{{letter}}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="users" *ngIf="checkForLetter(letter)">
       <div class="user" *ngFor="let usersByLetter as userByLetter">
          <p>{{userByLetter}}</p>
       </div>
  </div>
   <div class="users" *ngIf="!checkForLetter(letter)">
       <p>Not available</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by **simple JS** by creating an Object map and leveraging Angular's keyvalue filter:

**TS File**

```
let obj = {};
let arrayOfNames = ['Albertson, Mike',  'Aprot, Paul', 'Art, Boris', 'Cak, Lori',
'Callart, Ben'];

function getNamesGroups(arrayOfNames){
  const initCharCode = 65; // ASCII for 'A'
  const lastCharCode = 90; // ASCII for 'Z'
  let obj = {} //Map to store grouping
  let start = 0; // initialiser for second loop 

  for(var i = initCharCode; i<= lastCharCode; i++){
  
    let init = String.fromCharCode(i); // Get the actual character
    // Initialise the obj map's parameter
    if( obj[init] === undefined){
        obj[init] = [];
    } 
    for(var j = start; j<arrayOfNames.length; j++){
      let begCharAr = arrayOfNames[j].charAt(0);
      if(init === begCharAr){
        obj[init].push( arrayOfNames[j] );
      } else {
         // Store where next to start looping in next iteration
         start = j;
         break; // start from the next char
      }
    }
    
   }
return obj;
}
```

**HTML File**

Leverage angular's **keyvalue** filter for *ngFor

```
<div *ngFor="let group of obj | keyvalue">
    <div><b>{{group.key}}</b> </div>
    <ng-container *ngIf="group.value.length > 0">
       <ul>
          <li *ngFor="let name of group.value>
             <span>{{name}}</span>
          </li>
       </ul>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="group.value.length === 0">
       <div>No users available</div>
    </ng-container>
    
</div>
```

Here is a working[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dvhnrf57/)